# Image slider showing the edge of the next slide in internet explorer 7 (width issue)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer, flexslider

I'm building a site that uses an image slider on the home page.

You can see the site here... http://dev.ridethetrafalgarway.com/front-end/

It's working well, apart from the edge of the next slide being visible when viewed in Internet Explorer 7 (IE7).

It's puzzling me as all items appear to be set to use a width of 950px, but if you inspect the element in IE7 it uses a width of 942px.

Any ideas on how to get IE7 to behave will be much appreciated!

Thanks in advance,

Tom

Comment: There's rather a lot of code here. Could you reduce it to a jsFiddle? Also: it looks like your problem may not be IE-specific. I'm in Firefox 15 and see a thin sliver of white appear to the right of your image at the end of the animation.

Comment: PS Don't get too worked up about IE7. Google and Facebook have phased out support for it, and it should be virtually extinct in about a year's time.